# Converting JavaScript to TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Is there a "correct" order to start converting JavaScript to TypeScript? In my case, everything is mostly in Angular so there are a few controllers and services.

What would should be the **first step**? This is what I currently have:

- App.js
- Controller1.js ...
- Service1.js ..
- angular/jQuery.js

*More information*: I am using VS Code to do this and the project I would like to convert is a SharePoint app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a tool to convert JavaScript files to TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412164/is-there-a-tool-to-convert-javascript-files-to-typescript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What would should be the first step? This is what I currently have:

Add a `tsconfig.json` with `allowJs` set to `true`. TypeScript *understands* JavaScript! Then you will start the change the extensions of the file from `.js` to `.ts` one by one.

## More

I did a video on the subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmKXXI_ck7w and also created a tool (that you can use in combination with vscode or whatever other IDE you want) to help people like you: http://alm.tools/ .